# Why is the golang range operator implemented with declaration of a local variable?

Tags: go

When looping using the golang `range` operator combined with the address-of `&` operator we can get a somewhat unexpected behaviour.

Take the example:

```
list := []int{1, 2}
pointerList := []*int{}
for _, value := range list {
    pointerList = append(pointerList, &value)
}

fmt.Print(*pointerList[0], *pointerList[1])
// Prints: 2 2
```

This prints `2 2` because the variable `value` is only declared once and will change value for each iteration (while the address of `value` stays the same).

Q: Why does the go compiler not interpret the above code as if `value` was replaced by `list[i]`, like so:

```
list := []int{1, 2}
pointerList := []*int{}
for i := range list {
    pointerList = append(pointerList, &list[i])
}

fmt.Print(*pointerList[0], *pointerList[1])
// Prints: 1 2
```

If I'm not mistaken it is possible to do this interpretation for any use of `range` in a for loop. The behaviour seems more predictable and should be more performant if iterating over large objects (no extra copying to the local variable).

The example code:

https://play.golang.org/p/y89nMxVgBEs

https://play.golang.org/p/qHnJXMuHKdJ

Comment: it seems that new temporary object is created when you use `range` so the address is not the same as the original list you want to refer to. Check this : https://garbagecollected.org/2017/02/22/go-range-loop-internals/

Comment: I understand what the problem is – the question is about the motivation for the language design.

Comment: If you have a question about someone's motivation, you would have to ask them - in this case, the Go language designers.

Comment: @Adrian If asking on Stackoverflow is a good idea as well has been brought up here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36850/language-design-questions-on-SO

Comment: @LearnOPhile did you actually read that post? Because I agree with it. Questions from a language designer about designing a language are fine, questions asking why some other designer made some choice they made should be closed.

Comment: I did not interpret it that way. From the thread regarding types of questions: "Why does XXXX have YYYY [ok if not blindingly obvious]". Where did you get your perspective on this matter from?

Answer (score 4):

[Go does not have reference variables](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/29/there-is-no-pass-by-reference-in-go).

> It is not possible to create a Go program where two variables share the same storage location in memory. It is possible to create two variables whose contents point to the same storage location, but that is not the same thing as two variables who share the same storage location.

Since `list` is an slice of `int` and not a slice of `*int`, there should not be any expectation that the address of `value := list[i]` would be the same as the address of `list[i]`.  Since we already know that `value` is a copy, and that modifying it in any way won't affect `list[i]`, it is far more performant to allocate the memory for an `int` once, and overwrite it each iteration of the loop, than to allocate a *new* `int` every iteration, and garbage collect the old one.

Comment: If the scope of the variable had been defined to be inside the loop, then a new `int` is only required when the value escapes.  At least one of the Go authors now thinks that the language should have been defined that way, but the change is to disruptive to make.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, very insightful.
Do you happen to know if any author thinks it would have been best to only allow iterating over the index (not the value) with the range operator to get rid of this behaviour @ThunderCat?